# How to get response from server without sending client request?

Tags: wcf-data-services

I want create chat for automation website, so client not send any request to server for respond, instead server send respond to client when received a message from other client.
Thank you.

Comment: So what's your question? Just code what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the server can't call out to the client.  This effect however can be simulated w/ a couple tricks.  You'll want to look for a long-polling type solution like SignalR:

http://signalr.net/

Chat example (messages broadcast from server to clients):
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx